# Como puedo calcular el promedio de los máximos de varias listas en Python?

Tags: python

Por el momento intente los siguiente y no me esta dando el resultado que deberia ser 24,5:

```
def promtempmax(lista):
 maxi=[]
 prom=0
 a=0
 for i in lista:
   for j in i:
     if j>a:
       a=j
   maxi.append(a)
 prom=sum(maxi)/len(lista)
 return prom

lista=[[7,10,18,22,20,12],[9,13,16,21,25,19],[10,15,20,26,20,13],[11,14,22,25,22,20]]

print(promtempmax(lista))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar [comprensión de generador](https://es.acervolima.com/comprensiones-de-listas-de-python-frente-a-expresiones-de-generador/) para hacerlo en una sola línea

```
lista=[[7,10,18,22,20,12],[9,13,16,21,25,19],[10,15,20,26,20,13],[11,14,22,25,22,20]]

def promtempmax(lista):
    return sum(max(sub_lista) for sub_lista in lista) / len(lista)

print(promtempmax(lista))
```

Esto devuelve `24.5`

Explicación:

Primero obtenemos el máximo de cada sub lista dentro de la lista y lo sumamos

```
sum(max(sub_lista) for sub_lista in lista)
```

Y lo dividimos entre el número de sub listas, que sería `len(lista)`

**Edición:** Si lo quieres seguir haciendo con tu código, el único problema es que `a` hay que inicializarlo cada iteración de `i`. Te recomendaría inicializarlo con `None` por si hay números negativos en las listas

Ejemplo completo:

```
lista=[[7,10,18,22,20,12],[9,13,16,21,25,19],[10,15,20,26,20,13],[11,14,22,25,22,20]]

def promtempmax(lista):
    maxi = []
    prom = 0
    for i in lista:
        a = None
        for j in i:
            if (a is None) or (j > a):
                a = j
        maxi.append(a)
    prom = sum(maxi)/len(lista)
    return prom

print(promtempmax(lista))
```

Esto devuelve `24.5`

Answer (score 1):

Para calcular los promedios podria utilizar la libreria *[Pandas](https://aprendeconalf.es/docencia/python/manual/pandas/)* y su lista de lista la transformara en una *[matriz](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matriz_(matem%C3%A1tica))* en la cual podra facilmente calcular el promedio de la siguiente manera:

### Nota:

Si esta utilizando algun editor de codigo y aun no tiene instalado pandas lo puede instalar con el comando:

```py
pip install pandas
```

---

```
import pandas as pd
lista=[[7,10,18,22,20,12],[9,13,16,21,25,19],[10,15,20,26,20,13],[11,14,22,25,22,20]]
df = pd.DataFrame(lista)
print(df)

    0   1   2   3   4   5
0   7  10  18  22  20  12
1   9  13  16  21  25  19
2  10  15  20  26  20  13
3  11  14  22  25  22  20
```

### Resultado:

Para extraer el promedio utilizamos ***¡Solo una linea de codigo!***

```
promedio=df.max(axis=1).sum()/df.shape[0]
print(promedio)
24.5
```

Comment: Buen día, lo que el OP está solicitando es el promedio total de los máximos de todas las sub listas, en tu respuesta se calcula el promedio por sub lista

Comment: Ya mismo corrijo, muchas gracias.

Comment: Sr @HeytalePazguato , ya he corregido muchas gracias por la aclaración

Comment: Jaja no me digas señor jaja, háblame de tú. Saludos

Comment: Solo una pequeña aclaración, la "matriz" en pandas se denomina DataFrame y si bien es una buena solución, no creo que sea tan buena para datos bastante pequeños, recuerda que pandas importa muchos otros módulos para poder funcionar.

Comment: Me referí a *matriz* en ves de *DataFrame* porque si el OP apenas esta comenzando en este magico mundo es mas facil asimilar el termino de *matriz* que *DataFrame*